# getJSON, split results and append x results on scroll down

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, lazy-loading, getjson

I'm trying to build a image masonry with data retrieved via getJSON. Because there are to many results returned from getJSON and the page get's slow, I try to create chunks from these results, so that i can append more items only on scroll down.

I get my images this way:

```
function chunkArray(myArray, chunk_size){
    var results = [];

    while (myArray.length) {
        results.push(myArray.splice(0, chunk_size));
    }          
    return results;
}

$(document).ready(function () {

    // enable masonry
    var grid = $('#gallery').masonry({
        itemSelector: '.gridItem',
        columnWidth: '.gridSizer',
        percentPosition: true,
        transitionDuration: 0
    });

    // get all images
    $.getJSON("images.json", function (data) {

        var images = [];

        $.each(results.images, function (i, image) {

            var url = image.path + '/' + image.filename;

            images.push('<a href="' + url + '"><img src="' + url + '"></a>');

        });

        images = $(images.join(""));

        // create chunks with 50 images each
        images = chunkArray(images, 50);

        // append items to grid
        grid.append(images[0]).masonry('appended', images[0]);

    });

});
```

This appends the first 50 results to my gallery. But i don't know how to achieve the appending of the next 50 images when scrolling down.

Or is there a better / easier approach for doing this?

Thanks

Comment: do you want something like this : `[ ['<a href="img/001.jpg"><img src="img/001.jpg"></a>'], ['<a href="img/001.jpg"><img src="img/001.jpg"></a>'] ... ]` ?

Answer (score 0):

rewrite your foreach loop to:

```
var itemsPerPage = 50, page = 0
var images = [], image;
for (var i=0;i<itemsPerPage;i++)
{
    image = results.images[i+itemsPerPage * page];
    // the rest of your code
}
```